# Add argument to function without caling that on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem maybe very simple for you, but I spend more time for find a solution. Well, my problem: I am using jquery.ui dialog in my web app. I made a dialog, it must call a function by name `before_close` before closing dialog. My *dialog* look like that:

```
jQuery('#edit_user_form').dialog({
   'autoOpen':false,
   'title':'Изменить',
   'modal':true,
   'position':['center',60],
   'width':600,
   'resizable':false,
   'close':before_close
});
```

And it is *before_close* function:

```
function before_close (text) {
    $('#edit_user_form .update-dialog-content').html(text);
}
```

As you see, *before_close* have an argument. Can I bind the argument when I create dialog

```
jQuery('#edit_user_form').dialog({
   'autoOpen':false,
   'title':'Изменить',
   'modal':true,
   'position':['center',60],
   'width':600,
   'resizable':false,
   'close': before_close(anytext) // or before_close.apply(anytext) 
   /* above code called before_close when the dialog was created */
});
```

How can I add the argument for call `before_close` on closing dialog ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it can be solved by using "arguments" property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an `anonymous function` & call `before_close(anytext)` from it

```
jQuery('#edit_user_form').dialog({
       'autoOpen':false,
       'title':'Изменить',
       'modal':true,
       'position':['center',60],
       'width':600,
       'resizable':false,
       'close': function(){before_close(anytext);} // or before_close.apply(anytext) 
       /* above code called before_close when the dialog was created */
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The `close` parameter expects a function definition, and you provide it with a function call. You can solve this by wrapping it in an anonymous function:

```
'close': function() {
    before_close(anytext);
}
```